# How can I get this review plugin working?

Tags: plugins, octobercms, review

I installed a review plugin on my blog. This is the URL to the plugin:  https://octobercms.com/plugin/vojtasvoboda-reviews.

The review stars are not showing on my site. Can anybody help me what may be the cause of the review stars not showing?

Comment: Are you seeing the plugin in the admin interface? What code are you using to display the reviews on the front end? We need more information to help you.

Comment: did you add the component mentioned in the documentation to the page showing the posts?

Answer (score 0):

according to https://octobercms.com/plugin/vojtasvoboda-reviews

Go to the CMS tab in the navigation menu => Components => search for this component => click and drag it to the posts page

**or**

add this code to the posts page

```
{% if reviews is not empty %}
<div class="reviews">
    <h3>What our customers say about us?</h3>
    <div class="stories">
        {% component 'reviews' %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```